# How to check a column for duplicate values and return rows containing them

Tags: mysql

I am writing a script operating on SQL. The query is to check picked column (in this case kolumna1, kolumna2 or kolumna3) for duplicate values. Then, after finding these values I want to return every row containing such value. For example, looking at the table I have, if I look through kolumna1 column one of the duplicate values would be in row (id) 2 and 8. So in this case I would want to return whole second and eighth rows.
Of course main goal is to return every row with a duplicate value, this was just a simpler example.

The table:

```
INSERT INTO `tabela_testowa` (`id`, `kolumna1`, `kolumna2`, `kolumna3`, `kolumna4`) VALUES
(1, 'wartosc1', 'wartosc2', 'wartosc3', 1),
(2, 'warosc21', 'wartosc22', 'wartosc23', 5),
(3, 'wartosc31', 'wartosc22', 'wartosc32', 6),
(4, 'wartosc54', 'wartosc43', 'wartosc45', 4),
(5, 'wartosc43', 'wartosc23', 'wartosc34', 4),
(6, 'wartosc43', 'wartosc54', 'wartosc43', 2),
(7, 'wartosc54', 'wartosc52', 'wartosc53', 8),
(8, 'wartosc21', 'wartosc22', 'wartosc43', 4),
(9, 'wartosc43', 'wartosc33', 'wartosc45', 9),
(10, 'wartosc87', 'wartosc62', 'wartosc11', 3);
```

so far I've managed to write a query that almost works properly. By almost I mean that it returns the duplicates, but only one time for each one.

Query:

```
SELECT id, kolumna1 
FROM tabela_testowa
GROUP BY kolumna1
HAVING ( COUNT(kolumna1) > 1 );
```

Edit: I am using mysql. Also, to clarify I want to search through only one column that I choose in search for the duplicate values, then display whole rows containing them (of course I mean both rows, like the 2nd and 8th ones).

Comment: First decide on your DBMS, `MYSQL` <> `SQL SERVER`

Comment: I just noticed that i have actually chose the sql server tag. Im using mysql only, changed it in the edit now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If am not wrong you are looking for this

Works in both `Mysql` And `Sql Server`

`Correlated Sub-Query` method

```
select * 
from Yourtable A
Where Exists (select 1 from Yourtable B where a.kolumna1 =b.kolumna1  
              HAVING  COUNT(1) > 1 )
```

Another approach, filtering `kolumna1` which is having more than one record and joining with your table

```
Select A.* From Yourtable A
(
select kolumna1 
From Yourtable
Group by kolumna1 
Having Count(1) > 1
) B 
ON A.kolumna1= B.kolumna1
```

**Update :** Scope of the alias name ends when the select query ends you cannot use it like that. Try this way

```
SELECT *
FROM   tabela_testowa tab1
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   tabela_testowa tab2
               WHERE  tab1.kolumna1 = tab2.kolumna1
               HAVING Count(1) > 1)
```

---

If you are using `SQL SERVER`

```
Select * From
(
select *,Count(1)Over(Partition by kolumna1) as cnt
from Yourtable 
)A
Where cnt > 1
```

Comment: Correct me if Im wrong, but aren't you using two tables here? Because I want to check only one column in one table. Or is your answer using aliases?

Comment: @AleksanderSadaj - To achieve the result you need to refer the same table twice. To differentiate the refered columns we need to use alias name

Comment: I tried the first solution. exact code i used:


    SELECT id, kolumna1, kolumna2, kolumna3, kolumna4
    FROM tabela_testowa AS tab1;

    SELECT id, kolumna1, kolumna2, kolumna3, kolumna4
    FROM tabela_testowa AS tab2;

    select * 
    from tab1
    Where Exists (select 1 from tab2 where tab1.kolumna1 =       tab2.kolumna1  
              HAVING  COUNT(1) > 1 )

i get an error saying 
#1146 - Table 'baza_danych_testowa.tab1' doesn't exist

But if im not wrong, i declared the aliases at the beginning, so what is wrong here?

Comment: I am sorry it took me so long to respond. The update works! Thank you very much, Ive been struggling with it for a whole day!